# Oracle endeca partial update changes not reflecting in endeca ref app

Tags: oracle, indexing, endeca, dgraph

I am trying to implement oracle endeca partial update . My changes are visible in the forge output file which is placed in the `dgraph_input/updates` directory but the change is not reflecting in the endeca reference app.

Can anyone help me in this. I am using MDEX 6.2.2 . The Dgraph configuration is as follows :

```
  <!--
    ########################################################################
    # Dgraphs
    #
  -->
  <dgraph id="Dgraph1" host-id="ITLHost" port="15000">
    <properties>
      <property name="restartGroup" value="A" />
      <property name="updateGroup" value="a" />
      <property name="DgraphContentGroup" value="Test" />
    </properties>
    <log-dir>./logs/dgraphs/Dgraph1</log-dir>
    <input-dir>./data/dgraphs/Dgraph1/dgraph_input</input-dir>
    <update-dir>./data/dgraphs/Dgraph1/dgraph_input/updates</update-dir>
<args>
<arg>--updatedir</arg>
<arg>./data/dgraphs/Dgraph1/dgraph_input/updates</arg>
</args>
  </dgraph>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was solved by manually starting the dgraph with the --updatedir flag.
Still trying to find a way to enable the flag in the dgraph brick in AppConfig.xml